# test app in windows azure without creating trial account

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

i am extremely new to the `windows azure` and somehow i migrated my `web app` to the `azure`, so that now i am able to run it within azure emulator without creating any trial account on `azure`,
but still the data accessing from the existing `database`, i want to test the database too in the sql azure emulator.
thus i googled alot, but not found any satiable solution/way !
can anyone help me about this... ?

thanks

Comment: there is no such thing "SQL Azure emulator". Please refer to the online documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx) for further reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) to check your local database for compatibility with Windows Azure SQL Database without needing an actual Azure SQL database.

For the most part, though, it's compatible with SQL Server 2012, with these exceptions

> SQL Server 2008 R2 Features Not Supported by SQL Database The
>   following features that were new to SQL Server 2008 R2 are not
>   supported by Windows Azure SQL Database: SQL Server Utility
>
> SQL Server PowerShell Provider. PowerShell scripts can be run on an
>   on-premise computer, however, and connect to Windows Azure SQL
>   Database using supported objects (such as System Management Objects or
>   Data-tier Applications Framework).
>
> Master Data Services
>
> SQL Server 2008 Features Not Supported by SQL Database The following
>   features that were new to SQL Server 2008 are not supported by Windows
>   Azure SQL Database: Change Data Capture
>
> Data Auditing
>
> Data Compression
>
> Extended Events
>
> Extension of spatial types and methods through Common Language Runtime
>   (CLR)
>
> External Key Management / Extensible Key Management
>
> FILESTREAM Data
>
> Integrated Full-Text Search
>
> Large User-Defined Aggregates (UDAs)
>
> Large User-Defined Types (UDTs)
>
> Performance Data Collection (Data Collector)
>
> Policy-Based Management
>
> Resource Governor
>
> SQL Server Replication
>
> Transparent Data Encryption
>
> SQL Server 2005 Features Not Supported by SQL Database The following
>   features that were new to SQL Server 2005 are not supported by Windows
>   Azure SQL Database: Common Language Runtime (CLR) and CLR User-Defined
>   Types
>
> Database Mirroring
>
> Service Broker
>
> Table Partitioning
>
> Typed XML and XML indexing is not supported. The XML data type is
>   supported by Windows Azure SQL Database.
>
> Other SQL Server Features Not Supported by SQL Database The following
>   features from earlier versions of SQL Server are not supported by
>   Windows Azure SQL Database: Backup and Restore
>
> Replication
>
> Extended Stored Procedures
>
> SQL Server Agent/Jobs

([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx))

The other thing to bear in mind is that you have to code much more defensively against Azure SQL, as occasional failures are more likely, so you need exception handling with retry operations.

Comment: found the wizard but confused how to use it !

Comment: Point it at your local database and choose to generate Script Only, it will create a script with problem areas highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to create local copy of azure sql database using sqlazuremw tool

1.) Go to website https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/  and download Sql Database MW tool. As per your sql server version. There are different setup available to work with different version on sql server.

2.) Start exec “SqlAzureMw.exe”

3.) Once application open it show different option to select.

- Select database option from analyze/migrate section
- Select target server from dropdown.
- Click next

4.) After click next it will open a popup to select our source database. Here you need to fill sql azure credential then click on connect button.

5.) On successful connect, you will get list of data base.

6.) Select source database and click next.

7.) After clicking next you will get option to select database object that you want to import. If you want to import all the object then just click next button and then Click next button again.

8.) Click yes on message box that say “Ready to generate sql script”

9.) It started script generation and you will get status  on current window about the process. Once it done. Click next button.

10.)    It open a pop up window again. Here you need to fill your destination database detail and in your case it is your local database. Click connect.

11.)    Once connect. Select database where you want to export db object.

12.)    Click next and choose yes on message box “Execute script against destination server?”

13.)    Once done you will get success status